# How to enable disabled gameobject in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

I want to disable a GameObject, for achieving this I have written a code like this:

```
GameObject go;
go = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
Destroy(go);
```

Then I am struggling to enable that disabled GameObject.

Could anyone help me on this regard?

Answer (score 2):

When calling `Destroy`, you .... destroy the gameobject, you don't disable it. Instead, use [SetActive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).

Moreover, avoid using functions like `FindXXX`, especially multiple times. Add a reference in the inspector instead

```
 // Drag & Drop the gameobject in the inspector
 public GameObject targetGameObject ;

 public void DisableGameObject()
 {
      targetGameObject.SetActive( false ) ;
 }

 public void EnableGameObject()
 {
      targetGameObject.SetActive( true ) ;
 }

 public void ToggleGameObject()
 {
      if( targetGameObject.activeSelf )
           DisableGameObject() ;
      else
           EnableGameObject();
 }
```

Else, find the object once, either in the start function or when you try to disable the gameobject. Keeop in mind that `FindXXX` functions can't find disabled gameobject (most of the time)

```
 // Drag & Drop the gameobject in the inspector
 private GameObject targetGameObject ;

 public void DisableGameObject()
 {
      if( targetGameObject == null )
             targetGameObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
      if( targetGameObject != null )
           targetGameObject.SetActive( false ) ;
 }

 public void EnableGameObject()
 {
      if( targetGameObject != null )
           targetGameObject.SetActive( true ) ;
 }

 public void ToggleGameObject()
 {
      if( targetGameObject == null )
          targetGameObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");

      if( targetGameObject == null )
          return ;

      if( targetGameObject.activeSelf )
           DisableGameObject() ;
      else
           EnableGameObject();
 }
```

Comment: If it is tagged MainCamera, there is no need to search for it, use Camera.main

Comment: The poster used `GameObject.FindWithTag`, thus, I also used it. This is the general approach. Maybe, he will change his mind and he will want to find a gameobject with a different tag.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question But .....

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Tip:

go.SetActive(!go.activeInHierarchy); // Toggle gameobject.

go = GameObject.FindWithTag("TADA") // Better